# Twitter OAuth using signpost in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, oauth, twitter-oauth

I want to authorize a Twitter account using the [Signpost library](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/). I have done this in Android but want to implement it on BlackBerry. I have searched for tutorials on how to authorize a Twitter account but didn't find any useful resources. Can any one provide a reference or tutorial for implementing it on BlackBerry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Twitter API ME](http://www.twapime.com/)?